# Azure devops merge type for release branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-flow

I am just about to merge my release branch into master with an on-premises Azure DevOps environment.
When I go for completing the Pull Request I am given four merge types options:

- Merge (no fast-forward)
- Squash commit
- Rebase and fast-forward
- Semi-linear merge

I would prefer keeping all my history intact, making sure to minimize issues on hotfixes or future release branch. I am trying to follow the git-flow process.

Usually I would use a Rebase with fast-forward, however (when I select "Squash") a message  on the screen says:

"Consider using a no-fast-forward merge if you plan to use the sourcfe branch for future work".

What does that mean? Is Rebase with fast-forward not safe?

Thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, if your *source* branch has merge commits that you wish you to retain, then the **only** merge type you should choose among those 4 is the first one, "Merge". In Git-Flow, merging any protected branch into another would always necessitate a regular merge. (`release` or `hotfix` into `master` or `develop`, etc.) The reason is any of the other 3 merge types will "pop" the merge bubbles and you'll lose the information provided by the merge commits.

Note you can still use semi-linear merge for feature branch merges into protected branches, in fact I personally prefer that when using Git-Flow. Here are some more details about [when you can and can't use semi-linear merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63621528/184546).

Comment: fantastic clarification, thanks a lot for this.