# How to handle PRs when using Gitflow?

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

How many PR reviews should I be doing when running Gitflow? I have a feature branch with quite a few changes on it. I've PR'd it with reviews and merged into the develop branch. There may be like one or two small changes left before the release. When I go to merge the release code into the main branch, should I be doing another full PR review. Especially since most of the changes are going to be the same as the stuff I reviewed in the PR from feature to develop, it seems like a waste of time, but also with my current understanding, if I don't do reviews on the second PR from release to main, some things could slip through the cracks. How do you handle this redundancy or is there some sort of industry standard method for this? Thanks!

One thought is maybe PRs and their reviews are just required going from feature to develop?

Comment: This is extremely project- and/or team-dependent. It is also dependent on your release process. If you are working in a team, it is better to discuss this with your teammates especially your potential reviewers.

Comment: @GinoMempin I don't understand how this is extremely dependent. The git flow workflow is a well defined workflow. Unless I'm missing some context, the feature branches will always have to be merged into develop, and develop into release, and release into main. This means there will have to be merges with similar changes, so surely there has been some, at least unofficial, standards developers have adopted for how to handle reviewing these changes multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I go to merge the release code into the main branch, should I be doing another full PR review?

No. In fact, if you can, consider automating those "Git Flow merges"<sup>1</sup>. If you manage to automate them, then you will only need to have manual intervention if there are conflicts. In properly structured Git Flow, it's not possible to have conflicts when merging `release` or `hotfix` into `main`, but it is possible to have conflicts when merging `release` or `main` into `develop`.

> One thought is maybe PRs and their reviews are just required going from feature to develop?

That's correct, but note you also need PRs with full code reviews for all feature branches into any shared branch, which includes `develop`, `release`, and `hotfix`.

**General Git Flow Tips:**

1. After merging `release` into `main`, there are some (minor) advantages<sup>2</sup> to merging `main` into `develop` instead of `release` into `develop`. Try it, you may like it.
2. When merging feature branches into a shared branch, you can use a variety of merge strategies, such as regular merge, squash merge, and my personal favorite, [semi-linear merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59714347/184546) or rebase merge. However, when merging a Git Flow *shared* branch into another shared branch, you **must** use a regular merge. In strict Git Flow you should also use `--no-ff` for these regular merges which is necessary when merging `release` or `hotfix` into `main`.
3. Consider protecting all Git Flow shared branches so that you have no choice but to do a code review in order to merge any feature code in. If you wish to automate the Git Flow merges, do so in a way such that the automation job is able to bypass the PR requirement.
4. If an automated Git Flow merge fails (presumably due to conflicts), you can do the  merge yourself, by creating a new temp branch from the *target* branch, merging in the *source* branch, resolving the conflicts, and then PR'ing that temp branch into the *target* branch. With this PR the only thing a code reviewer needs to look at is perhaps a sanity check of the included files, and then the merge conflict resolutions. Regardless of how you normally complete your feature branch PRs, this kind of PR has only 2 options: regular merge with either no-fast-forward, or, perhaps surprisingly, this would be the one scenario where a fast-forward merge would be allowed. The reason is that you already created the merge commit in your PR, and the resulting graph is the same as if the automated merge worked without conflicts. If you decide to go with fast-forward here, make 100% that you merged the *source* branch into the *target* branch instead of the other way around. If you aren't sure, then use `--no-ff` when completing this PR as well. It's better to have an extra unnecessary merge commit than to accidentally flip the first-parent history.

---

<sup>1</sup> "Git Flow merges" refers to any merge of one *shared* branch into another as required by Git Flow. Examples include merging `release` into `master`, `release` into `develop`, `master` into `develop`, `hotfix` into `master`, `hotfix` into `release`, etc.

<sup>2</sup> After merging `release` into `main`, some advantages of merging `main` down to `develop` instead of `release` down to `develop`, are: 1.) You don't build up a bunch of merge commits sitting all alone on `main` from each release. If they build up, when you eventually have a `hotfix`, all of those lonely merge commits get brought down to `develop` all in one shot, which looks kind of strange when you're looking at what commits are new with that merge. 2.) Before merging `release` into `main`, it may be useful to do a sanity check to confirm that `release` is fully ahead of `main`, because if it isn't, then it's probably because there was a `hotfix` that someone forgot to merge down into `release` and it's about to get blown away. One of the easiest ways to confirm you don't have this problem is to check that the tip of `main` is reachable by the `release` branch.

Answer (score 0):

We have adopted gitflow the following way and that is what WE do:

1. we have multiple micro-services each in its own repository.
2. We use **master** branch for current product development towards the next release.
3. each feature/bugfix developed on the master branch gets proper Review.
4. Once release is announced each repository branches a **release** branch right from the head of the master branch.
5. The release branch undergoes qualification. (full product testing).
6. if bugs are found on the release branch a hotfix is produced. On the release branch the hotfix is properly tested/reviewed and then merged back to master branch, we rely on automated tests developed along with the feature to insure the successful merge.
7. if we find a bug on the master branch and we know it would be the same bug on the release branch, then we do tests on both branches independently. Because we want to insure that the hotfix is still compatible with the branches, as it gets diverged in code the older it becomes. The hotfix travels to the release branch by means of cherry-pick.

The amount of reviews one want/has to do would depend on many different factors. Some are due to company policies or industry regulations, some would depend on how much branches become different due to aging... etc.

We try to be conservative but with understanding that reviews take a lot of time and effort. As such, we try to keep release branches short, e.g. in our case lets say ~4 months and we update deployed product as soon as new release comes.

In general, the more differences you have between the branches, the more attention you might want to pay to your merges. Fast-forward merges should not required additional reviews as it is the same already tested code.

By the way, you only want to use gitflow if you have to maintain multiple release branches.

Disclaimer: I slightly simplified and optimized the workflow for easier explanation, it is not full representation of the actual process.

Comment: Is this really the git flow though?  Sounds like you don't even use a develop intermittent branch. Maybe that's part of your disclaimer. But if not, ignoring the hotfix branch, you won't even ever have the chance to need multiple similar PRs because you're only rolling two branches. Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it sounds like you're doing master->release, whereas the gitflow is typically feature->develop->(maybe release)->main. You can probably see with the latter that there are a lot more opportunities to have PRs with the same changes.

Comment: It is an optimized git-flow. Git-flow suggests to have more branches when it is really needed. If you look at it Master/main branch is just a collection of squash commits. It has no practical meaning, only creates more hassle and more PRs to take care of. In the original git-flow one wants to have clean master branch, without intermediate dev commits. We overcome it by using tags on the master and smart git commands to get clean history of master. Hotfix branch is the same as a feature branch, the changes are done via PR to the release branch or master from feature/hotfix branch.

Comment: we did the optimization in order to reduce amount of merges between branches and the problems you are currently facing with re-reviewing merge commits.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much, that makes sense! I'm still hope someone can address the conventional gitflow though lol :)

Comment: If I may say - you should re-think what you are trying to achieve. Do not try to adapt something what is very theoretical. You will still end up in a custom solution that satisfies all your needs and is a compromise between convenience and the price for that convenience. Your price is unnecessary PRs you have no clue what to do about and you already expressed you don't want to do double work. If you want to stick with original gitflow then you have to do the reviews for each PRs you create.

Comment: Is the gitflow just theoretical? I've heard it's the most popular flow out there. I guess the question is whether your last sentence is accurate. "If you want to stick with original gitflow then you have to do the review for each PRs you create." This is the whole point of this post - to figure out if this is the case or if someone somewhere figured out some sort of solution that at least minimizes the duplicate reviews. If I just abandon the conventional gitflow, I lose all the benefits that come with having a middle-man branch - primarily "develop".

Comment: @ClayCasper Git Flow is not just theoretical. It's still a popular flow for projects that have a long release cycle and you don't want to have code freezes. (Let's say "long" is more than 24 hours.)